# How to filter out done reminders in Google Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail, reminder

I want to show only not done reminders.

For now, I figured out

- `is:reminder is:done`, which show only done reminders
- `is:reminder is:snoozed`, which show only done snoozed reminders

How can I show pending reminders ?

Comment: Does `is:reminder is:-done` or `is:reminder -is:done` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
is:reminder -is:done
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out that by default all pending reminders are pinned. So this will do the trick :

```
is:reminder is:pinned
```

Obviously, if you manualy unpin your reminder without setting it done, it won't work.

Of course, I will accept any better answer than mine.

Answer (score -3):

I have a better one:

```
is:reminder !is:done
```

Comment: This does not seem to return any reminders at all?

Comment: Google generally uses `-` for NOT, rather than `!`.